# MongoDB aggregation map-reduce(group by) to nested hash

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

For a quick example, I have a data set here:

```
{ name: "a", age: 2, sex: "male" },
{ name: "b", age: 4, sex: "male" },
{ name: "c", age: 3, sex: "female" },
{ name: "d", age: 5, sex: "female" },
{ name: "e", age: 7, sex: "female" },
```

I want to reform it to:

```
{ 
  sex: male, people: { 
    "a": 2,
    "b": 4,
  },
  sex: female, people: {
    "c": 3,
    "d": 5,
    "e": 7,
  },
}
```

I have tried countless solutions including $group(addtoset) and $unwind. Actually, $addtoset partially does the job, but $addtoset can only generate a new array. What I need is aggregating to a hash.

Is it possible to make it happen in MongoDB?

Comment: The structure is what is simply impossible as all "hash/map/object" whatever you want to call it keys must always be "unique". What possible purpose would this serve as single document anyway? Regarless of the collection method, your "people" element must by defintiion be an "array" instead, as there is no way to structure with multiple occurances of the same key.

Comment: Thanks Blakes, it was my mistake. The "name" field is unique. I need the "people" element to be a hash for the following "$group" aggregation.

Comment: You still do not understand. Anything under a `{}` structure can only have the name "key" appearing once. You have listed the same thing several times in several places. It's not a matter of "can MongoDB do it", it's that the structure you propose is simply not possible. It sounds like all you are really after is the distinct names for either male or female, and you likely need neither in a single document. It's better to explain your real purpose here rather than come up with abstract examples as the latter will rarely solve your real problem.

Comment: I got a terrible example...I think I get it right now. The one I wanted is not a hash. Now, I think the question itself is correct. :)